# How Do I Create a Google Spreadsheet Formula to SUM data based on two variables

Tags: google-sheets

#### DATA SECTION:

So I have data in one sheet like this:

```
TYPE    AMOUNT     YES/NO
Pig         20     Y
Pig         30     N
Pig         10     Y
Cow         20     Y
Cow         30     N
Cow         50     N
Bat         10     N
```

#### RESULT SECTION

I'm using Google Spreadsheets and have a table in another sheet. I would like to have a formula (placed in the cells like the one labeled [=?]) that gives me sums like thus:

```
TYPE        YES      NO
Bat         [=?]    [=?]
Cow         20      80
Pig         30      30
```

But I still need the formula.

#### PROBLEM SECTION

I'm struggling. I want a formula in the results table that looks up in the data section for a match in type and SUMs the Ys for that type. I would like another formula that looks up in the data section for a match in type and SUMs the Ns for that type. I assume VLOOKUP or HLOOKUP, but I'm struggling getting the SUM in addition. I linked an example sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Asz9U8pYGDSPdEQ2NVJCLXZYNjBncjdzc0FNZ2t3ZVE&usp=sharing).

#### ADDITIONAL EDITS AFTER THE POST

I don't need a query. I just need a formula that replaces the [=?] for each column in the result section. I just put a ton of info there as an example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you add the following formula in the second sheet (A1).

### Formula

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A1:C9;"SELECT A, SUM(B) WHERE B IS NOT NULL GROUP BY A PIVOT C")
```

then the table will appear as you want.

### Explained

Here an explanation of the formula, from the inside to the outside:

- the `PIVOT C` transposes the unique results from column C (turning rows into columns)
- the `GROUP BY A` only filters out unique values in column A. (the same as sheet TABLE!A2)
- the `WHERE B IS NOT NULL` ignores empty cells
- the `SUM(B)` adds the result of the query
- the `SELECT A` simply displays column A, as unique values

If you're only interested in individual results, then I suggest using the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(SUM(FILTER(DATA!$B$2:B;DATA!$C$2:C=$B$1;DATA!$A$2:A=A2));"")
```

Here an explanation of the formula, from the inside to the outside:

- the `FILTER` function will retrieve the amounts for range `B2:B`, column B without the header, by filtering range `B2:B` for "No" and range `C2:C` for "Yes".
- the `SUM` function will add them together.
- the `IFERROR` will leave a blank cell if an error occurred (not result).

### Screenshot

[image]

### Example

See example file I've prepared, where both samples are present: **[SUM data based on two variables](https://docs.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdG9ZQjdSRllvc2J4cU5NWVZsTWF2UlE&usp=sharing)**

### Note

The formula in the example file is a bit different (the range is set to contain complete columns).

Comment: I knew you'd come through with an answer.

Comment: So, I trust this is the answer, but I don't understand it. Can you explain?

Comment: Actually, I realize what happend. I need a formula for to replace the cell marked [=?] not a query that reformats the data. The data will be a long list of rows and I need a different order than what is show. I just used those as an example.

Comment: @Dorje Thanks for your feedback !! I've altered my answer as well. I hope this is the answer you're looking for. Have you noticed, both table are the same?

Comment: This is it! Thanks so much for the answer and the care in explaining it. I appreciate it.

Comment: I adopted this solution for some of my spreadsheets (tks Jacob). Can I migrate for the new Google Sheets without any problems? Sorry for ask as an answer, I'm new here and can't make a comment.

Comment: @EduardoPontes The `QUERY` function will work the same in the new Google Spreadsheets.

Answer (score 0):

Similar result - slightly different approach:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF('DATA'!$A$2:$A&'DATA'!$C$2:$C;$A2&B$1;'DATA'!$B$2:$B))
```

Comment: -1; Your answer yields `0`, see last sheet in the example file I created. Perhaps you can enlighten us and show us show it works?

Comment: Please take a look: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnPo68pL0jwddGFmTzFFTzlXYzdVT0FVakpRREl1VGc&usp=sharing)

Comment: The `QUERY` formula also calculates the unique entries, sums them up and presents the whole table. What's not fast about that? Look at the third sheet.

Comment: I don't think that `QUERY` isn't doing a good job here. My wording was misleading...

Comment: Dorje wanted a formula to place in the cells like the one labeled [=?].

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data is in Sheet DATA starting A1 and `TYPE` is in A1 of a different sheet, then in B2 copied across and the pair copied down:

```
=sumifs(DATA!$B:$B,DATA!$A:$A,$A2,DATA!$C:$C,left(B$1))
```

Depending upon Sheet's locale may require `;`s instead of `,`s.

[SUMIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496)
[LEFT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094079)