# How to use an IF statement over several cells?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm making a budget for myself. Currently, my Google Spreadsheets looks something like this:

```
----A---- -----B----    
     food         50
  alcohol         20
     food        120
    dance         10
   garden         20
     food         20
    dance         10
```

I would like to get the total amounts like this:

```
----E---- -----E---- 
     food        190
  alcohol         20
    dance         20
   garden         20
```

I can use an IF statement on a single cell so the IF statement would be:

```
=if(A1="food",B1,0)
```

but how do I do it over several cells and SUM values together?

Is there a function that allows me to calculate the total value of column B if column A is equal to "some text"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is best done like this:

### Formula

1. `=QUERY(DATA!A:B;"SELECT A, SUM(B) WHERE B IS NOT NULL GROUP BY A")`
2. `=QUERY(DATA!A:B;"SELECT A, SUM(B) WHERE B IS NOT NULL GROUP BY A Label
     SUM(B)'Units'")`

### Explained

If you include headers, then the `QUERY` function will add them as such and alter them accordingly, ie. `SUM title` or `COUNT title`....etc. You can also added a custom label to the calculated columns, see 2<sup>nd</sup> example (3<sup>rd</sup> sheet). The rest of the function will perform as standard [SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL).

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[sum over several cells](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdERZNVRHZFdCY1Y0WVc2TG1VTHR3aHc&usp=sharing)**

### References

1. [SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL)
2. [QUERY formula](https://support.google.com/drive/table/25273?hl=en)
3. [Query Language Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)
4. [Question with same techniques used](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/41684/29140)

Comment: I ended using the SUMIF statement

    =SUMIF(range to be matched, criteria,sum range)

=SUMIF($A$1:$A$7,E1,$B$1:$B$7)
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Luen that's also possible, but far more laborious. If you're interested, I prepared an example overview with the usage of `SUMIF` in combination with `UNIQUE`.

Answer (score 1):

You ask for an IF statement but have accepted an A that does not require that so may wish to consider a pivot table. The coding for this is "behind the scenes", so no formula or function is necessary:

[image: WA49362 example]

The row sorting is a 'bonus' and usually convenient but it does mean more work would be required if to order the output exactly as you show, for example with:

```
=sort(E2:F5,2,false)
```

(if the pivot table is moved into E2:F6 as shown).

For as simple an example as you show further versatility would be of little use but with a larger data set other features of a pivot table might be appreciated and could involve no more than an additional few clicks. For example how many of each `A` value (eg in the case of `food` here `3`), or the average of `B` by each `A` value (eg in the case of `dance` here `10`).